# Dynamic Programming To calculate the combinations

Tags: combinatorics, dynamic-programming

This is a problem from a past contest at topcoder : [Problem](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=12338).

Its solution is given here : [Solution [Scroll Down to Penguin Emperor]](http://apps.topcoder.com/wiki/display/tc/SRM+566)

I am unable to understand how the section with subheading "Combinations are associative" works. What is actually going on in this step ? How is the convolution property being used ? Or the Associative property of Combination ? How is the exponentiation squaring being performed ?

**EDIT**

*Problem Statement*

You are Given N cities numbered from 0 to N-1 in a circular order.
You are currently at city index 0.
On **first** day you can move from your your current city with index **i** to a city with index **j** such that

```
j = (i+N-1)MOD N 
or
j = (i+1)MOD N
```

On **second** day you can move from your your current city with index **i** to a city with index **j** such that

```
j = (i+N-2)MOD N 
or
j = (i+2)MOD N
```

and so on. So on Day **x**, you can move from your your current city with index **i** to a city with index **j** such that

```
j = (i+N-(X MOD N))MOD N 
or
j = (i+(X MOD N))MOD N
```

You **have** to travel on each day.

Given the number of Days **M**, find the total number of ways, you can travel starting from city index 0 such that at the end of M days you are back to city index 0 , modulo 1000000007.

The solution given is as following :

```
final int MOD = 1000000007;
// Discrete convolution:
int[] combine(int[] A, int[] B)
{
    int n = A.length;
    int[] C = new int[n];
    // Skipping when B[i] = 0, is a key optimization:
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) if (B[i] != 0) {
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            int k = (j - i + n) % n;
            C[k] += (int)( (A[j]*(long)B[i]) % MOD );
            if (C[k] >= MOD) {
                C[k] -= MOD;
            }
        }
    }
    return C;
}
// Exponentiation by squaring, for our convolution operation:
int[] power(int[] A, long x)
{
    int n = A.length;
    int[] R = new int[n];
    R[0] = 1;
    while (x > 0) {
        if ( (x & 1) != 0) {
            R = combine(R, A);
        }
        A = combine(A, A);
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return R;
}

public int countJourneys(int numCities, long  daysPassed)
{
    // Generate R and Q:
    int[] Q;
    int[] R = new int[numCities];
    R[0] = 1;
    Q = R;
    for (int i=1; i<=numCities; i++) {
        //B holds T[i]
        int[] B = new int[numCities];
        B[i % numCities] = 1;
        B[numCities - i] = 1;

        R = combine(R, B);

        if (i == daysPassed % numCities) {
            Q = R;
        }
    }
    R = power(R, daysPassed / numCities);
    R = combine(R, Q);
    return R[0];
}
```

countJourneys(N, M) is called to get the answer.

Comment: Please copy the problem and solution here.

Comment: ^Added the problem and solution code

Comment: I don't see any "Combinations are associative" subheading in this question.  Questions should be self-contained.  So what is the question?  And, what have you tried, and where do you get stuck -- what don't you understand?  Are you familiar with what the word "associative" means?

Comment: @D.W.: The heading was given in the link to the solution. But since Yuval pointed out that I should put the problem statement and solution in the question itself the "Combinations are associative" header is not relevant anymore. I just wanted to know how exactly discrete convolution is working in the above solution and how Exponentiation by squaring is being applied to the convolution operations. Both of the problem title are included in the solution as comments.

Comment: If some of the text in your question isn't relevant any more, you should click the edit button to remove it.  And what's your question anyway?  The first sentence that ends in a question mark refers to this thing that you say isn't relevant anymore.  What's up with that?  If what you want to know is how discrete convolution works in this solution, you should have (a) asked that question, and (b) not asked other distracting questions that are apparently irrelevant.  Bottom line: I encourage you to put more effort into writing a coherent, logical, well-organized, self-contained question.

Comment: Please get rid of the source code and replace it with ideas, pseudo
    code and arguments of correctness. See 
    [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/64/) and 
    [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/390/) for related
    meta discussions.

Comment: But that is my question... How are these properties being implemented in the following code.
How can I remove the code i such cases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use dynamic programming. For each day $k$, we find the number of ways (modulo $p = 1000000007$) to get from $0$ to $x$ for each $x \in \{1,\ldots,N\}$. Given the array $A_k$ for day $k$, the array $A_{k+1}$ for day $k+1$ is given by
$$ A_{k+1}(x) = A_k(x-k-1) + A_k(x+k+1), $$
where all indices are modulo $N$. The actual computation is done modulo $p$.

In your case, it seems that $M \gg N$, and then this method is a bit slow. That's why we want to use convolution. There is another way to describe the calculation above. Consider formal variables $x_0,\ldots,x_{N-1}$ that satisfy the rule $x_i x_j = x_{i+j \pmod{N}}$ (for concreteness, we could take $x_j = e^{2\pi i (j/N)}$; but we could also just treat them as formal variables.) We represent the array $A_k$ in the form
$$ A_k = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} A_k(i) x_i. $$
We have $A_0 = x_0$ and $A_{k+1} = (x_{k+1} + x_{-k-1}) A_k$ (all indices modulo $N$). This kind of multiplication is known as *convolution*, and it satisfies all the usual rules of multiplication (it is commutative and associative).

When $M$ is big, we want to take advantage of the fact that $A_k = A_{k \pmod{N}}$. So
$$ A_k = \prod_{i=1}^N (x_i + x_{-i})^{\lceil (k-i+1)/N \rceil} A_0. $$
The idea now is to compute $(x_i + x_{-i})^d$ using *repeated squaring*, which you can look up. For example, to compute $X^{10}$ we would compute $X,X^2,X^4,X^8$ and multiply $X^2$ and $X^8$ (more generally, we look at the binary expansion of the exponent). Given all the factors, we multiply everything together and then look at the coefficient of $x_0$.

Since we only want the result modulo $p$, we do all the computations modulo $p$.